# How can I use wxPython to create plain 2D space and plot points on that by mouse clicks?

Tags: python-2.7, plot, wxpython, 2d

I want to use wxPython to build a 2D space where user can plot points by clicking on the space.

Afterwards, I want to store coordinates of points into a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a working example in wxPython demo. Download it from the official site and find "Cursor" example. Below, I copy the relevant part from "Cursor".

In the panel constructor, bind the left down event.

```
self.win.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnDrawDot)
```

And, do something like this

```
def OnDrawDot(self, evt):
    # Draw a dot so the user can see where the hotspot is
    dc = wx.ClientDC(self.win)
    dc.SetPen(wx.Pen("RED"))
    dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush("RED"))
    pos = evt.GetPosition()
    dc.DrawCircle(pos.x, pos.y, 4)
```

wxPython demo is quite a valuable resource.